# Won't write to a text file

Tags: c#, winforms, file, filestream, streamwriter

I have created this to a form. If receives all the info and seems to work, but when I check the text file nothing is written there, and it only lets me run the form twice before erroring out. Anyone see the problem?

```cs
const string FileName = "Friends.txt";
Friend friend = new Friend();
FileStream file = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
FileStream file2 = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite); 

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(file2);

    try
    {
        friend.FirstName = firstName.Text;
        friend.LastName = lastName.Text;
        friend.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber.Text;
        friend.Month = Convert.ToInt32(birthMonth.Text);
        friend.Day = Convert.ToInt32(birthday.Text);
        write.WriteLine(friend.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("Wrote " + friend.ToString() + " to file.");
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message + " Please reenter the information.");
    }
    firstName.Clear();
    lastName.Clear();
    phoneNumber.Clear();
    birthMonth.Clear();
    birthday.Clear();
    write.Close();
    file2.Close();
}
```

Comment: I know people have already answered this, but if you are going to say "it errored out", at least say what the error text was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use files like that. They are being opened once only when the class is instantiated. And then at the end of `enter_Click()` you are closing the file, so the next time you call `enter_Click()` the file is closed and it fails.

Create the files *inside* `enter_Click()` so that they are opened and closed each time it is called.

You should use the `using` keyword to ensure they are closed even if an exception occurs.

Your code should look more like this:

```
private void enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (FileStream file2 = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(file2))
        {
            try
            {
                friend.FirstName = firstName.Text;
                friend.LastName = lastName.Text;
                friend.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber.Text;
                friend.Month = Convert.ToInt32(birthMonth.Text);
                friend.Day = Convert.ToInt32(birthday.Text);
                write.WriteLine(friend.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Wrote " + friend.ToString() + " to file.");
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message + " Please reenter the information.");
            }
            firstName.Clear();
            lastName.Clear();
            phoneNumber.Clear();
            birthMonth.Clear();
            birthday.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

There is an alternative way you *could* handle this - you could open the file once only, and close it only when the class is disposed. Then you could just keep appending to the file without having to keep reopening and closing it.

I *do not* recommend doing it that way. It would be more efficient, but it is far far more prone to errors, and if your program crashes there's a danger that the file could have data not written to it - which could corrupt the file.

It's much better to play it safe and keep opening and closing the file, unless you are writing a *lot* of data to it; only then might you want to consider this alternative way.

Comment: Yep. See the examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Comment: I put it outside the click method because I have more buttons calling the same file. Do I just need to create a new FileStream within each button click?

Comment: You should consider having a common private method in your form that all button click events call to write to the file.

Comment: @Evan Yes, like AJ says, put all the code that writes the data to the file into a single method and call it from the button handlers. Use `using` inside the method as I showed you in the answer. You might want to pass the filename into the method as a string parameter, to reduce coupling between the method and the containing class. (Keeps things cleaner)

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush and/or close your streamwriter, and you should really dispose it as well.
The best way to handle all of this is with a `using` statement:

```
using(var write = new StreamWriter(file2)
{
    //... your code
}
```

As @Matthew Watson said, you shouldn't be creating your FileStream objects as globals in the form, either.  Create them in the click event, and put your filestreams in using statements as well:

```
using(var file2 = new FileStream("Friends.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
{
    using(var write = new StreamWriter(file2)
    {

    }
}
```